# Abrir la cámara frontal y trasera en Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, cámara

Ya tengo la cámara hecha y esta abre solo la cámara frontal, pero quiero crear un botón para abrir la cámara trasera o frontal.

Este es mi código:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,
    UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    var sessionOutputSetting = AVCapturePhotoSettings(
        format: [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
    )
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    @IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(
            deviceTypes: [
                AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera,
                AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,
                AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera
            ], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
            position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified
        )
        for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
                do {
                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                    if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                        captureSession.addInput(input)

                        if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput) {
                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(
                                session: captureSession
                            )
                            previewLayer?.videoGravity =
                                AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                            previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation =
                                AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)  
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error")
                }
            }
        }
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
```

**⚠️ PROBLEMA CON ORIENTACIÓN EN CÁMARA FRONTAL ⚠️**

Tengo un problema con esto. La orientación de la foto tomada en la cámara frontal parece ser incorrecta.

Así aparece en la vista antes de tomar la foto con la cámara frontal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así cuando tomo la foto con la cámara frontal, parece que se aplica la orientación de espejo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la cámara trasera no existe este error, todo fluye con normalidad

Como puedo solucionarlo, @Wilson muy amablemente me dio una posible solución que actualmente forma parte de mi código, pero parece que no funciona. Sigo teniendo el mismo error.

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma que hize es, agregando un boton en la vista y luego conectando un IBAction al boton llamado `changeCameraPosition` para luego dentro de este metodo, ejecuto 3 otros metodos:

- `getDesiredCameraPosition`: que obtendra la **posicion** de la camara ya sea la frontal o trasera.
- `getCamera`: en base a la posicion de camara que le pasemos a esta funcion, nos obtendra la **referencia** a la camera que nos interesa
- `setCamera`: Teniendo esta **referencia** `cameraAvailable`, le dicemos a iOS que muestre esta referencia en la camara fisica, ejecutando esta funcion `setCamera`.

### Code:

```
  @IBAction func changeCameraPosition() {
    let desiredCameraPosition = getDesiredCameraPosition(by: currentVideoInput)

    let cameraAvailable = getCamera(byPosition: desiredCameraPosition)

    setCamera(with: cameraAvailable)
  }
```

---

## Source code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,
  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
  var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
  var sessionOutputSetting = AVCapturePhotoSettings(
    format: [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
  )
  var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
  @IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

  // added
  var currentVideoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?

  @IBAction func changeCameraPosition() {
    let desiredCameraPosition = getDesiredCameraPosition(by: currentVideoInput)

    let cameraAvailable = getCamera(byPosition: desiredCameraPosition)

    setCamera(with: cameraAvailable)
  }

  // added
  func getDesiredCameraPosition(by videoInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput?) -> AVCaptureDevicePosition {
    let currentCameraPosition = videoInput?.device.position
    var desiredCameraPosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.back

    if currentCameraPosition == .front {
      desiredCameraPosition = .back
    } else if currentCameraPosition == .back {
      desiredCameraPosition = .front
    }

    return desiredCameraPosition
  }

  // added
  func setCamera(with camera: AVCaptureDevice?) {
    if let cameraAvailable = camera {
      let videoInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraAvailable)

      if let videoInput = videoInput {
        self.captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        self.captureSession.removeInput(self.currentVideoInput)

        if self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput) {
          self.captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
          self.currentVideoInput = videoInput
        } else {
          self.captureSession.addInput(self.currentVideoInput)
        }

        self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
      }
    }
  }

  // added
  func getCamera(byPosition position: AVCaptureDevicePosition) -> AVCaptureDevice? {
    let deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType] = [.builtInDuoCamera, .builtInTelephotoCamera,.builtInWideAngleCamera]
    let session = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(
                        deviceTypes: deviceTypes,
                        mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                        position: position
                  )

    if let session = session {
      if let devices = session.devices {
        for device in devices {
          if device.position == position {
            return device
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return nil
  }




  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
  }
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(
      deviceTypes: [
        AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera,
        AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,
        AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera
      ], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
         position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified
    )
    for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {
      if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
        do {
          let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
          if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
            captureSession.addInput(input)

            // added
            currentVideoInput = input

            if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput) {
              captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
              previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(
                session: captureSession
              )
              previewLayer?.videoGravity =
              AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
              previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation =
                AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
              cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            }
          }
        } catch {
          print("Error")
        }
      }
    }
    captureSession.startRunning()
  }
}
```

## UPDATE (take picture functionality):

```
extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

  @IBAction func takePictureButtonTouched() {
    captureImage()
  }


  func captureImage(){
    let connection = self.sessionOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if let connection = connection, connection.isVideoOrientationSupported {
      connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
    }

    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                         kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                         kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160]
    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat


    self.sessionOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
  }

  func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {
    if
      let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
      let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
      let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {



      var capturedImage = UIImage(data: dataImage)

      let cameraPosition = currentVideoInput?.device.position

      // si la camara es la frontal,
      // hacemos un flipping a la imagen
      if let image = capturedImage,
         cameraPosition == .front {

        capturedImage = UIImage(
          cgImage: image.cgImage!,
          scale: image.scale,
          orientation: UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored
        )

      }

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(capturedImage)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hazme saber si necesitas alguna clarificacion, espero te sirva, Saludos compañero!

Comment: Perfecta tu respuesta, me sirvió mucho pero quisiera saber como puedo capturar la foto ya que estoy teniendo problemas con la orientación de esta. Me gustaría que proporcionara alguna solución 

Comment: no problem Sebastian, he actualizado mi solucion incluyendo la captura de la foto, aunque este update no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta formulada, la puse en fin, si tienes alguna pregunta respecto a la parte de captura de la foto, te sugiero que crees otra pregunta en stackoverflow y...... no te olvides marcar la respuesta como valida ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Wilson, gran trabajo 

Comment: no hay porque, gracias!

Comment: Aún sigo teniendo el problema de la orientación de la imagen, he actualizado mi pregunta para que pueda ver la fotos de mi problema

Comment: Sebastian, el cambio fue en didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer, ahora deberia estar funcionando bien, hazme saber si te funciono.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Wilson, problema solucionado 